# Modify a particular posterbox from tcolorbox in a sequence

Tags: tcolorbox, posters, split

Here is an example of sequence with poster in tcolorbox:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {showframe,
    columns=2,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=18cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
  ]

  \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  ]{
    name=A,
    sequence = 1 between top and row2 then
    2 between top and bottom
  }{\scriptsize\lipsum[1]}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

I wonder if it could be possible to change settings only for block called A2. For example I want to disable the placeholder style when empty or to choose different colors from A1.

Furthermore I wonder if I could fit a long text to the entire sequence.
If I use the "fit to" option I obtain a 
unique long box instead of two separated ones:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {showframe,
    columns=2,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
  ]

  \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  fit to=5.85cm and 20cm,
  ]{
    name=A,
    sequence = 1 between top and row2 then
    2 between top and bottom
  }{\lipsum[1]}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is a solution based on the @BambOo answer and on the opacity option
(if it could be useful to someone).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {showframe,
    columns=2,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
  /tcb/placeholder/.style={
    enhanced jigsaw,
    opacityframe=0.0,
    opacityback=0.0}
  ]



  \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  ]{
    name=A,
    column = 1,
    row=1,
  }{}

  \posterbox[
  colframe = blue,
  ]{
    name=A,
    column = 2,
    row=1,
    rowspan=2,
  }{}


  \posterbox[
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colframe = red,
  opacityframe=0.0,
  opacityback=0.0
  ]{
    name=A,
    sequence = 1 between top and row2 then
    2 between top and bottom
  }{\lipsum[1]}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your `\posterbox` differently using `column` and `between` instead of `sequence`. See [`tcolorbox`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) v4.14 manual section 19.2 page 399

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {showframe,
    columns=2,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=18cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
  ]

  \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  ]{
    name=A1,
    column=1,
    between= top and row2
  }{\scriptsize\lipsum[1]}

  \posterbox[
  colframe = blue,
  ]{
    name=A2,
    column=2,
    between= top and bottom
  }{\scriptsize\lipsum[1]}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** Solution maitaining the `sequence` approach.

This solution is based on the redefinition of the `placeholder` style of `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

 %\tcbset{placeholder={colframe=blue,colback=blue}}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {showframe,columns=2,rows=2,spacing=3mm,height=14cm,width=12cm},
  boxes={colframe=red,colback=white},
  /tcb/placeholder/.style={colframe=blue,colback=white}
  ]
  \posterbox[
    colframe = red
  ]{name=A,
    sequence = 
    1 between top and row2 then
    2 between top and bottom
  }{\lipsum[1]
  }

\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

Result when empty

[image]

Result when filled

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I choose to use the sequence, because I want to fill the posterbox A2 when I've a long text

Comment: @Source Just to clarify, what do you mean by *fill A2 when you got long text* ? You mean that the content of A2 is the content that does not fit in A1 ?

Comment: The thing is that as far as I know, `sequence` consists in splitting a single `\posterbox` into multiple graphical objects so there is no reason for it them to be differently styled. I keep looking

Comment: yes you're right, as in my first example in which one single \lipsum is splitted into the 2 boxes.

Comment: I think there is a way to do this by redefining the `placeholder` style, I should be finished in a few